# Java Spring/Apache POI/THymeleaf - Formatting style from MSWord to HTML

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi, thymeleaf

I have an application built on Spring MVC that reads a MSWord DOCX with Apache POI and returns it to a HTML Thymeleaf web page. But I am not able to maintain the text formatting styles like bold, italic, font-color, font-size, etc.

The Spring Controller method returns a ModelAndView with a variable called docDetail loaded with a XWPFDocument object from loadResource().

```
[...]
@GetMapping("/document")
public ModelAndView document() {
    [...]

    modelAndView.addObject("docDetail", fileService.loadResource());

    return modelAndView;
}
[...]
```

The HTML Thymeleaf fills a fragment while iterate over the paragraphs from the document.

```
[...]
<div th:fragment="doc-detail">
        <div th:each="par : ${docDetail.paragraphs}">
            <p th:text="${par.text}"></p>
        </div>
</div>
[...]
```

And the result appears as plain text. I have not tried Apache Tika yet.
So, How can I keep the styles from the document to the web page?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code for instantiating `fileService` in the controller? Specifically, the POI parts?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your issue. You are using a `XWPFDocument` and scanning through the text without regard to style. In POI, font and style is encoded in `XWPFRun` types which are one level down from paragraph. So you're going to need an extra `th:each` to loop through the runs and apply the style for each. You code will look something like this:

```
<div th:fragment="doc-detail">
    <div th:each="par : ${docDetail.paragraphs}">
        <div th:each="run : ${par.runs}">                  
            <span th:if="run.bold"><b th:value="run.text"></b></span>
            <span th:unless="run.italic"><i th:value="run.text"></i></span>                                    
            <span th:unless="1==1" th:value="run.text"></span>                                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Greetings, now I see the paragraph properties at the "run" atribute. I think each formatting need its own step, I'll try to search some more. Thank you for the insight.